# Checking for new emails from within Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

Within Rails, how can I listen for new mail coming into the boxes of certain accounts. I want to implement a simple "post-by-email" service, which gets the new content of the email and makes a blog post or sth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a post explaining some of the options. A later post also covered my way of testing these options. The mail gem is great for parsing. You just have to decide the best option for you to optain the messages.

http://steve.dynedge.co.uk/2010/09/07/incoming-email-in-rails-3-choosing-the-right-approach/

Answer (score 1):

You could try [this gem](https://github.com/titanous/mailman).

Comment: Hmm, seems not very practical. I'd like to have my own mail server, and keep an "internal" email account per user, so that any mail sent to it, gets submitted to the database. I am pretty sure there are plugins or sth for Rails that could do this

Comment: Edited with a more appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to parse my emails.

```
class Receiver < ActionMailer::Base

  def self.parse(email)
    reply_separator = /(.*?)\s?== ADD YOUR REPLY ABOVE THIS LINE ==/m
    comment_text = reply_separator.match(email.body.to_s)
    # ...
  end
end
```

The `email` object here is just a `Mail::Message` object which I get from using the `gmail` gem to read an inbox. If you're not using GMail then you should be able to use plain ol' vanilla Mail gem to connect to the mail server and then get the `Mail::Message` objects that way.

Comment: How do I get the periodic checking working, should I set up some sort of a cron util or sth?